# php array count values in 4 deep array

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to count how many times a delivery date is in my array but i seem to only be able to count the first level.

```
array (size=48)
  '2000-01-01' => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '2000-01-01' (length=10)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'van' => string '0' (length=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=619)
              'drop' => string '0' (length=1)
              0 => 
                array (size=29)
                  'id' => string '18137' (length=5)
                  'order_number' => string '13550' (length=5)
                  'reference' => string '' (length=0)
                  'delivery_date' => string '2000-01-01' (length=10)
```

I've tried:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_flip(array_column($output, 'delivery_date')));
```

and

```
$array = array_map(function($element){
    return $element['delivery_date'];
}, $output);

$array2 = (array_count_values($array));

print_r($array2);
```

in the end i either end up with a array to string error or the value 1.

how Would i go about counting these?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting 2 or 3 from your sample array?  Are you checking keys and values?  Is your array structure strictly conforming to the displayed depth?  Are the targeted values always in subarray level 1 and subarray level 4?

Comment: Please clarify your question so that it is not closed with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675330/counts-occurrences-in-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/array_walk_recursive) and increment an array value every time the `delivery_date` key is present in the array at any level:

```
$counts = [];

array_walk_recursive(
  $output,
  static function ($value, string $key) use (&$counts): void {
    if ($key === 'delivery_date') {
      $counts[$value] = ($counts[$value] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: @Progrock It indicates that the closure doesn't need to access the current object (`$this`), and can also be a slight permance improvement. It's entirely optional, but my [PhpStorm plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended-) suggests it so I took it as a habit to add it.